# rails cannot find gems even after bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am currently trying to start my rails server after doing a `bundle install`. However, when I try to do `rails s`, this error pops up

`Could not find gem 'byebug (= 9.0.6)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. Run bundle install to install missing gems.`

I then run `bundle install` but the same error pops up. I've also tried getting rid of `byebug` in the gemfile but it just gives me the same error but with a different gem. I've tried installing byebug individually using `gem install byebug -v 9.0.6` but the same problem persists.

This is my gemfile

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '5.1.6'
gem 'puma',         '3.9.1'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.3.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.7.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.12'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.6', platform: :mri 
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.5.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.1.5'
  gem 'spring',                '2.0.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: What version of `byebug` is in you Gemfile.lock file?  You may need to run `bundle update` and then `bundle install`.

Comment: I have `byebug (9.0.6)` currently in my gemfile.lock, I ran a `bundle update` and then a `bundle install` but still ran into the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You should run your rails server with `bundle exec rails s` to be in the context of the bundle.

Comment: I ran with that command but it is giving me the same error :|

Comment: If you have only rails gem in your Gemfile, the same error occurs ?

Comment: It gives me a new error :
/Users/usr/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in require': Could not load the 'listen' gem. Add gem 'listen'` to the development group of your Gemfile (LoadError)

Comment: ok, try to add now same gems like before but without copy/pasting them.

Comment: `puma` works fine, but with anything else i get the Could not find gem 'uglifier3.2.0' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. error

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a following line in .bundle/config

```
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: "test:development"
```

After removing that line and running `bundle install`, everything works fine.